# How to run gulp tasks with different parameters depending on the argument on terminal

Tags: gulp

I have a shared SCSS source files which must be compiled and copied into different project folders.

I have a build task which calls 2 tasks, clean and styles(to compile/minify and copy to build folder).

My source SCSS files are shared between all websites however the destination folders are different.

I would like to be able to run: build websiteA and then clean build folder inside websiteA and compile files from a shared folder and copied to build folder inside Website A.

```
var assetsDir = '_Assets';

var buildStyleWebsiteA = 'WebsiteA/Assets/build';
var buildStyleWebsiteB = 'WebsiteB/Assets/build';


gulp.task('clean-websiteA', function (cb) {
    return del([buildStyleWebsiteA ], cb);
});

gulp.task('styles-websiteA', ['clean-websiteA'], function () {
    return gulp.src(assetsDir + '/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(buildStyleWebsiteA + '/css'))
        .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
        .pipe(cleanCss())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(buildStyleWebsiteA + '/min/'))
        .pipe(liveReload());
});

gulp.task('build-websiteA', ['styles']);
```

PS: I also have same tasks for websiteB (build-websiteB, clean-websiteB, and style-websiteB).
So I ended up with repetitive code and I know there must be a better way.

What I would like to have is provide website name as a parameter for gulp command and then it runs clean and style using correct folder related to that website.

How can I refactor my code to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use environment variables to accomplish this rather than arguments.

```
var buildDir = process.env.BUILD_DIR + '/Assets/build';
```

Then you would call it as:

```
BUILD_DIR=websiteA gulp build
```

Comment: 'BUILD_DIR' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Shouldn't it be "gulp build BUILD_DIR=websiteA"?